# Insert dynamic listbox options in Tinymce popup editor

Tags: tinymce

I am trying to create dynamic listbox values but getting this error in console:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'active' of [

Here's my code( pasting only the code for listbox ):

```
 body: [
                {
                    type: 'listbox',
                    name: 'type',
                    label: 'Panel Type',
                    value: type,
                    'values': get_author_list(),
                    tooltip: 'Select the type of panel you want'
                },
        ]
.....
```

And I am calling this function to get dynamic list...

```
  function get_author_list() {
    var d = "[{text: 'Default', value: 'default'}]";

    return d;
}
```

I am guessing that the values in listbox only takes static var and not dynamic. But I need to insert dynamic values in this list. Please can anyone help me find a workaround. Is there any possibility to insert via ajax?

Thanks, in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem with the values helper was that it will only take array of objects and i was passing a string...I have corrected the code by passing an array of objects..Below is the corrected code..

```
body: [
        {
            type: 'listbox',
            name: 'type',
            label: 'Panel Type',
            value: type,
            'values': get_author_list(),
            tooltip: 'Select the type of panel you want'
        },
]
.....

function get_authors_list() {
    var result = [];
    var d = {};
    d['text'] = 'Default';
    d['value'] = 'default';
    result.push(d);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make a reference to another function in Javascript I don't think you need the () after get_author_list.

```
 body: [
            {
                type: 'listbox',
                name: 'type',
                label: 'Panel Type',
                value: type,
                'values': get_author_list,
                tooltip: 'Select the type of panel you want'
            },
    ]
```

Also, I don't think you need the quotes around the object.

```
 function get_author_list() {
    var d = [{text: 'Default', value: 'default'}];

    return d;
}
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined

My console log returns d as [{text: 'Default', value: 'default'}] so i am just calling get_authors_list in values as values take [{}] as param...

Comment: Did you remove the quotes? (I've made an edit to my post). Console.log should not return d as [{text: 'Default', value: 'default'}].

It should contain something like this: "[Object]0: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array[0]"

Comment: Actually I have fixed the problem myself..The d should be defined as an array of objects.. I will add the solution here